# Is there a way to specify which tests to run (from multiple files) in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I'm using Javascript with Cypress framework to automate tests.

How do I mark tests as tier1 , tier 2 etc. so that I could run only tests marked tier1 or tier2 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can group them by folders, and then use the *ignoreTestFiles*   and *testFiles* config params to ignore or use them, according to your needs.

You will have to use the route that matches all the tests inside the folder.

For example, you have three folders inside the integration folder called Tier1, Tier2 and Tier3. To indicate that Cypress should ignore tests inside Tier1 and only use Tier2 and Tier3 you have to add to your config:

> ignoreTestFiles: '**/Tier1/*.js'

Or if you prefer:

> testFiles: ['**/Tier2/*.js', '**/Tier3/*.js']

To know more about config params take a look to the Cypress docs: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Folders-Files

Comment: Thanks Veronica. Going by the two responses I;ve received, it looks like the only way to do it by putting all the tests in the same folder. I was looking for the equivalent of pytest markers to mark individual tests as Tier1 , Tier2 etc. so that both Tier1 and Tier2 tests could live in the same file or folder . Is that possible with Cypress ?

Comment: I do not know a way to do exactly what you want, but there are several ways to skip tests so you can choose the one that fits your situation the most. 
I also use the skip-test library https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cypress/skip-test 
because I work with several environments, so I have some flags in the environment config (that is located in a fixture) and can skip tests depending on that flag, i.e. skipOn(Cypress.env('config').skipTier1));

Answer (score 0):

- Set up different subfolders in your integration folder in Cypress, called "tier1", tier2", tier3"
- npx cypress run will still run all subfolders
- "npx cypress run --spec "cypress/integration/{subfolder}/*-spec.js" will run all tests in a specific subfolder